# Received a badge for a Community Wiki answer

Tags: discussion, badges, specific-answer

I recently received a [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer?userid=861716) for a community wiki answer. Of course I didn't mind, but I did wonder: why?

I CW-ed this no-brainer answer soon after I noticed that for some unfathomable reason it attracted lots of upvotes. I like rep points, but I also like to think I *deserve* them. Same for badges.

So I wonder, why do CW answers render badges ([except tag specialist badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)) while by nature they are anonymized? When a CW answer has been modified/improved many times by other users, is it justified that the original poster is still rewarded?

Probably there are some deep thoughts on this, but I couldn't find any information on it at meta, except *that* [we get badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) for CW posts.

Comment: In light of the (now deleted) answer confirming that this is intended behavior, you might consider giving this a title more along the lines of, "What's the motivation behind implementing foo as bar"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> When a CW answer has been modified/improved many times by other users, is it justified that the original poster is still rewarded?

It takes a certain amount of faith in the system/community to create a community wiki answer. As the original author, you voluntarily take on the very important role of *first actor* (aka *first mover*). You could be seen as launching a small collaborative project with every CW post you create.

This is a great thing to do but at the same time it's not something that people seem to do very often, probably because it means sacrificing the reputation they might otherwise gain. That's a strong disincentive (generally speaking – not everyone cares) for providing community wiki answers. And yet, marking an answer as CW sends a signal that this information should be aggressively curated for accuracy, which aligns very well with SO's mission.

I can't tell you why someone chose to implement badges for wiki answers in this particular way, but I also don't see any compelling reason to further disincentivize CW answers by changing this behavior (not that this is what you're suggesting). Consider that reputation gives you access to a whole array of privileges, while badges are primarily there to say, "You did a good job."

There are some privileges you can get from badges:

- ["Dupe-hammer" privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/254929);
- You must have [certain badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/254929) to be nominated in moderator elections (SO only).

But of these, the former considers only non-CW answers and the latter involves badges that have nothing to do with post scores (outside of meta, at least).

We know that badges exist as incentives for users to contribute productively to the site. Contributing a CW answer is no less productive than contributing a standard answer. Perhaps a better question is why we don't do more to reward the other contributors to a CW answer.

Comment: As an aside, I find myself using CW answers to avoid taking credit for content that already exists *within the network*, especially when copying answers between cross-site duplicates. I feel no such compulsion when copying over information from outside SE; but after thinking about your question, maybe I should.

Comment: OK, that could be a reason to keep giving badges. I like the idea to do more to stimulate improving answers, esp. CW answers. Whether or not you should mark answers as CW is up to you, after all, finding external sources takes effort too.